# Smoothing objective function

Tags: optimization, smoothing

I have a current problem where i have a continuous error real function of n-variables, which is computationally expensive and (possibly) has multiple local minima (optima). I want to somehow smooth the error surface and decrease the number of local minima with as low deformation as possible (may be controlled by a parameter) to the surface so that the global minima and main features of the surface is preserved. After which I can apply gradient decent or simulated annealing or other algorithms on it to get a better algorithm.

Can anyone point where to start on smoothing so that i can try to achieve what i want? Note that I am not knowledgeable enough in optimization techniques and statistics, but do point me to any resources/poitners which i can study to get into it.

Comment: Simulated annealing is unlikely to benefit from such smoothing. In fact, it might be harmed if the smoothed surface is any more costly (in time) to evaluate. Perhaps your question might better be cast in terms of finding computationally efficient approximations to the surface for the purpose of obtaining approximate global solutions. The potential advantage of revisiting it like this is that you would not then rule out non-smooth approximations (such as linear interpolators) and you would keep the focus on your ultimate problem rather than deflecting it into incidental or fruitless avenues.

Comment: Basically my target is to find better approximation by avoiding getting stuck in local minima. Any suggestions ?

Comment: SA does exactly that. More generally, I worry that smoothing the surface could cause you to find incorrect solutions, unless you can provide guaranteed control over the amount of smoothing (which could be difficult for an expensive computation).

Comment: My target is to reduce the number of local optima.Yes if the smoothing is done in a wrong way then the solution can be bad. I had a look at "Local Optima Smoothing for Global Optimization" by [Addis] [Locatelli] [Schoen] and a combination smoothing "Search-space smoothing for combinatorial optimization problems" [Schneider] [Dankesreiter] [Fettes] [Morgenstern] [Schmid] [Singer],I am not sure if they will help. 

SA will help with skipping local minima, but instead of going the SA way directly i want to try out if smoothing really will work in my case, or may be some other method.

Comment: And yes, basically i require to compute the gradient of the smoothed surface primarily analytically so that i can use GD.